# Angular using Jasmine and Karma getting - Incomplete: No specs found

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-runner

Angular using Jasmine and Karma getting - Incomplete: No specs found  but converting spec.ts file to spec.js getting error Error during loading: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module in

[image]

My Karma Config File

```html
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: "",
    frameworks: ["jasmine", "@angular-devkit/build-angular"],
    plugins: [
      require("karma-jasmine"),
      require("karma-chrome-launcher"),
      require("karma-jasmine-html-reporter"),
      require("karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter"),
      require("@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma"),
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: ["html", "lcovonly"],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
    },
    files: ["src/**/*.spec.js"],
    include: ["src/**/*.spec.js"],
    angularCli: {
      environment: "dev",
    },
    reporters: ["progress", "kjhtml"],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ["Chrome"],
    singleRun: false,
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `files` and `include` entries strange to me.

Try removing them:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: "",
    frameworks: ["jasmine", "@angular-devkit/build-angular"],
    plugins: [
      require("karma-jasmine"),
      require("karma-chrome-launcher"),
      require("karma-jasmine-html-reporter"),
      require("karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter"),
      require("@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma"),
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: ["html", "lcovonly"],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
    },
    // files: ["src/**/*.spec.js"],
    // include: ["src/**/*.spec.js"],
    angularCli: {
      environment: "dev",
    },
    reporters: ["progress", "kjhtml"],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ["Chrome"],
    singleRun: false,
  });
};
```

Try creating a new CLI project with the same Angular version as yours and compare the `karma.conf.js` with yours.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after upgrading to Angular 14 and tried many solutions. Finally, it turned out that my `test.ts` file was outdated. I created a new Angular 14 project and copied the `test.ts` from it to my project.

Previous:

```
/*
 * Prepare environment for unit tests.
 * This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files.
 */

import 'zone.js/testing';

import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting(), {
  teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false }
});
```

The new file looks like this:

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: {
  context(path: string, deep?: boolean, filter?: RegExp): {
    <T>(id: string): T;
    keys(): string[];
  };
};

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting(),
);

// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().forEach(context);
```

And it worked for me.

Nothing else needed to be changed.

Pay attention to

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

`karma.conf.js`:

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        // you can add configuration options for Jasmine here
        // the possible options are listed at https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Configuration.html
        // for example, you can disable the random execution with `random: false`
        // or set a specific seed with `seed: 4321`
      },
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    jasmineHtmlReporter: {
      suppressAll: true // removes the duplicated traces
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/test'),
      subdir: '.',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html' },
        { type: 'text-summary' }
      ]
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```